# Xcode simulator loaded something different from what's on storyboards

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, uistoryboard

I was testing my app and I click on iPhone 6 simulator and out of the blue instead of what I have in storyboards, the simulators loads something different. It loads my app but the app I had months ago when certain buttons were missing and it lined up my app differently. Then when I closed the simulator turned it back on again, everything loaded like normally with the right app. This happened twice before as well.

Why would the simulator load something different from what's in the storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solutions:

1. clean your project: `command` + `k`
2. reset the simulator under the **File**-tab in the task bar while the simulator is open
3. open the simulator and delete the app from it like you would on an actual device. This will force-reinstall the application to your simulator and it will work again.

I don't really know why it does that but I guess that might have something to do with cache or something...

Comment: You don't know why it does that? Do you mean this happens to people often or do you mean that as you're surprised something like that happened?

Comment: I mean that happens every once in a while. Did one of my suggestions work for you?

Comment: I don't know, the only way to find out if it truly worked is if once in a blue moon the wrong app loads. That happens very infrequently.